# when passing non member variable data to a constructor how to save them and use then in other member functions ? C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
 enum t_poi { Restaurant , bar , club , cinema }; 

class CPOI
{
private :
    t_poi m_type ;
    string m_description;

public :
    CPOI(t_poi type , string name , string description , double latitude , double longitude);
    void print();

};

CPOI ::CPOI(t_poi type , string name , string description , double latitude , double longitude){


    m_type = type;
    m_description = description;


}

void CPOI::print(){

  //here i want to print the other non member variables ( name , latitude and longitude ) 
}
```

**now i dont know how to save those 3 non member variables in order to  use them in other functions
NOTE : i dont want to make them member variables
**

Comment: You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: `NOTE : i dont want to make them member variables` -- Then how do you expect to save them?

Comment: Simply SIr , there is 5 attributes are being passed to the constructor of the class CPOI and this class has only 2 member variables t_type and description ... the issue is that according to the UML design of the project i cant declare the other 3 non member variables passed to constructor as member variables , also the print function shouldn't be talking any arguments , so i was asking for a way to save those 3 attributes passed to the constructor and use them in other member functions without changing the class design , sorry if it wasnt clear !

Comment: So you don't want to do the right and normal thing... because it's not in "the UML design of the project"? Oh deary me. Not only is that entirely the wrong approach to problem-solving in design, but why is your UML design specifying private members anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two options are

1) Make them member variables

2) Add them as arguments to the `print()` function, as shown below, then call `print` within the constructor (if that is the intention)

```
void CPOI::print(string name, double latitude , double longitude)
```

If you pass them to the constructor, but they are not stored in member variables, and not used as parameters for any functions called in the constructor, they are effectively useless.

Comment: thats tottaly true ! but this is how it was asked to be implemented in the project that name , long , lat are not a member variables and the print function shouldnt take any attribute ... your 100% right tho , thanks alot